# Importing Disrupts Format Of Cell

Tags: excel, import, format, cell, vba

my problem is related to the importation of data, when I do this action trough a macro linked to a button, the data from the other file comes into the target workbook and disrupts all the previous cell format there. It is like it transfers the same format from the source sheet that the data comes from.

I will post my code and if it isn't enough I will post the workbooks.

```
Sub ImportData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Path As String, Lstrw As Long
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Path = "C:\Users\DZPH8SH\Desktop\Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls" 'Para modificar ter acesso a pasta onde irá ficar o ficheiro

Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set TargetWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim n As Integer, targetRow As Long
targetRow = 3

'Para importar os sheets que o utilizador quiser, modifique o n "="

For n = 1 To 2

   With SourceWb.Sheets(n)
        Lstrw = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets(7).Range("A" & targetRow)
        'move the targetRow to the first empty row after pasting the source data
        targetRow = targetRow + Lstrw
   End With

Next
SourceWb.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks for any reply in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just doing a straight copy/paste, which will copy formats and values.  There are two options for just bringing through values (which I assume is what you want).

The first is to use `Range.Copy` to copy cells to the clipboard and then `Range.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` to just paste the values:

```
.Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Copy
TargetWb.Sheets(7).Range("A" & targetRow).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

The second option is to use the `Value` property to get and set cell values without affecting formats.  In this case you would have to modify your loop as you can't get all the values from a non-contiguous range in one statement (the `Value` property just returns the values from the first area in an array).  You would do something like:

```
targetColumn = 1
For Each sourceArea In .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Areas
    TargetWb.Sheets(7).Range(TargetWb.Sheets(7).Range.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn), TargetWb.Sheets(7).Range.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn + Lstrw - 1)).Value = sourceArea.Value
    targetColumn = targetColumn + 1
Next sourceArea
```

This is conceptually simple (`targetRange.Value = sourceRange.Value`) but looks ugly because of having to loop through areas, and construct the equivalent target range with the right number of cells.  But it is more flexible than the first option, and there probably are neater ways of getting the right target ranges.

Comment: I think the better is the first one. Thank you for the quick reply :D